# List View ,how to change Overscroll color

Tags: android

Hi i don't know what it is called so i don't know what to search for,hence here it is...

[image]

Please tell me what it is called and how to change it's color

This blue color appears when you pull a list view or a fragment.I want to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the Overscroll. You can set the drawable like this

```
setOverscrollHeader(R.drawable.the_header);
setOverscrollFooter(R.drawable.the_footer);
```

You can also set it on your ListView through xml:

```
android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/the_header"
android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/the_footer"
```

Comment: and it also appears in the fragment,is it called the same in fragments ?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava it's a ListView's attribute, it's called the same everywhere as long as it's a ListView.

Comment: no no,inside a fragment it appears on left and right...not on top and bottom

Comment: i gave a +1 however i can only accept your answer after a few minutes,and please reply to my prev comment

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava your fragment must have some View that's horizontally scrollable, because ListView is usually vertically-oriented.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava seems that ViewPager doesn't have such easy-to-use attribute. You could however try out [this library](https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride).

Answer (score 2):

There's a function setOverscrollHeader()
Use the drawable component within the parentheses.